# How to Test an IIS Module via Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis

I'm working on an IIS module written in C#.  I'm trying to test out some different types of functionality which is slowing down the development process.  Right now I make the code change, build it, move the DLL to my web folder and refresh the website in my browser.  This means I have to follow the stack trace every time an error occurs.

Is there some way I can run this directly from Visual Studio so if an error occurs VS will catch it and display the details allowing me to step back and forth through it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to attach VS to IIS process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long ad IIS loading modules DLLs you should be able to attach Visual Studio debugger to the IIS working process, try out to attach to the *w3wp.exe* process